# 502 error using Requests to search website in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Using a very basic program to search up a query on a website and print out the search results, why do I get a 502 error?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def main():
    url = "https://www.last10k.com/Search"
    dat = {'q':'goog'}
    resp = requests.get(url, params=dat)
    print(resp.content)
```

Comment: If you do `print(resp.url)` what do you get? Also I'd recommend using longer variable names... is `dat` supposed to mean `data`? Is one character worth confusing people? Same goes for `resp` --> `response`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a `User-Agent` header. Like this:

```
import requests

def main():
    url = "https://www.last10k.com/Search"
    dat = {'q':'goog'}
    resp = requests.get(url, params=dat, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Why of this requirement? [Wikimedia User-Agent policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and found that a mix of looking at the content and trying the request with a browser helped me find the solution. Maybe it will help you, too, so here is what I did:

My request was successful with a browser, then failed with python. The URLs were the same. So I used the debugger. You can also simply print stuff, but the debugger shows what all is to see and lets you explore what you otherwise have missed. And I found that the response content on the failed python-request was an error-message which googles to be a ruby-problem.

So there was some different behavior on the remote-side, but what causes it? Adding a User-Agent-header, as suggested, was nice, but did not change anything. So I looked at the other headers and found that the Basic Authentication string looked completely different.

My solution: I fed the python request with the wrong auth-data due to some reafactoring I made and the remote side was processing "permission denied" results somehow badly, which ended up in a 502 instead of a 403.