# I tried to print out the words of a title online, but instead, nothing shows up on the console

Tags: python

For practice, I wanted to build a word frequency counter in Python. I decided to use the title of a post on Reddit (if that isn't a problem) as an example for this. The first step for me was to get the words from that title, and put them into a list, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_words(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, features='html.parser')
    for word in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title may-blank loggedin'}):
        content = word.string
        every_word = content.lower().split()
        for every in every_word:
            print(every)
            word_list.append(every)


get_words('https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/comments/hje9ud/kemba_walker_im_a_single_man_with_no_kids_so_ima/')
```

But when I run it, nothing runs on the console (even when I decide to iterate through the title and print out all the words). Is there a reason for this? Is it because I'm using a big site like Reddit for an example?

Comment: Your call to `soup.find_all()` isn't finding anything, leading to the print statement never running.

Comment: But why isn't it finding anything? @bbnumber2

Comment: The class `loggedin` might be the problem - that seems unlikely to be present on the page you get from a plain `requests.get()` with no login credentials supplied.

Comment: You're right. The class changes for me depending on whether I'm logged in or not (prob cuz I'm using Old Mode in contrast to the newer mode). But even when I tried changing it to the class when I'm not logged in, I still get nothing when I run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably receiving a 502.
Instead of this:

```
source_code = requests.get(url).text
```

you should be doing this:

```
response = requests.get(url)
assert response.status_code == 200
source_code = response.text
```

and you will see it fail.

You need to add a "user agent" header. See this question:
[502 error using Requests to search website in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239698/502-error-using-requests-to-search-website-in-python)

Even at that, your soup selector is weird. You are looking for `a` elements with 'title' class but there are no such elements on that page. You probably should just get `<h1>` elements.

So this would work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_words(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, features='html.parser')
    for word in soup.find_all('h1'):
        content = word.string
        every_word = content.lower().split()
        for every in every_word:
            print(every)
            word_list.append(every)


get_words('https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/comments/hje9ud/kemba_walker_im_a_single_man_with_no_kids_so_ima/')
```

I tested this and it finds duplicate headers so maybe just use the first one, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_words(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, features='html.parser')
    content = soup.find_all('h1')[0].string
    every_word = content.lower().split()
    for every in every_word:
        print(every)
        word_list.append(every)


get_words('https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/comments/hje9ud/kemba_walker_im_a_single_man_with_no_kids_so_ima/')
```

Comment: It worked! Which is weird, considering I didn't need a user agent header when I made a web scraper using info on another site. But I have a question about the User-Header: Why 'Mozilla/5.0'? And thanks for the useful answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Mozilla. It can be anything you like.

Comment: Some sites don't enforce the user agent header requirement. Most big sites do though.

Comment: Ah, because I used eBay for the web scraper, and I could retrieve info fine without a user agent. So maybe eBay's an exception?