# Beutifulsoup sometimes print None sometimes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to scrape a image from a reddit post. But when I run this code snippet It show me html snippet sometimes, but sometimes it prints None (NO Error occurred). Anybody can tell me why? Here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/programmingmemes/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

img = soup.find('div', class_='_3Oa0THmZ3f5iZXAQ0hBJ0k')
print(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the return code of the request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/programmingmemes/')

if source.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

    img = soup.find('div', class_='_3Oa0THmZ3f5iZXAQ0hBJ0k')
    print(img)
else:
    print(f"Error (code {source})")
```

Also check if the `class` is constant during time (it may be randomized).

Comment: Thanks, but now it giving Error (code <Response [502]>) as output when I run it.

Comment: That is the error returned by the server, this is the explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239698/502-error-using-requests-to-search-website-in-python/43240776 it is suggested to use an user-agent to avoid it

Comment: and it shows this also Error (code <Response [200]>) .Seems like if clause doesn't work

Comment: edited the answer, i was missing the .status_code

Comment: But still giving error. Can't  I avoid error 502